# MyBatis/ Ibatis Error : The content of element type "update" must match

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, ibatis

We have update few rows and after updating rows, we want to return number of rows affected. We have written our xml file as follows

```
<update id="update" parameterClass="com.test.Delete">
        update entity_association set deleted = 1, syncTS = #syncTS# where
        assoc_entity_row_id in
        <iterate property="parentIds" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
            #parentIds[]#
        </iterate>
        and assoc_entity_type = #parentType#;
        <selectKey resultClass="int">
            select row_count()
        </selectKey>
    </update>
```

For returning number of rows affected count, when we add selectKey tag, we get error `"The content of element type "update" must match "(include|dynamic|iterate|isParameterPresent|isNotParameterPresent|isEmpty|isNotEmpty|isNotNull|isNull|isNotEqual|isEqual|  isGreaterThan|isGreaterEqual|isLessThan|isLessEqual|isPropertyAvailable|isNotPropertyAvailable)"`.

Is there any better way to  implement this ? selectKey tag works fine for insert.

Comment: it looks like the <update> tag may not contain the <selectKey> tag.  Check the myBatis / iBatis docs; I think an update already returns the number of rows updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that dtd schema validator causes this error. Depending on your version mybatis/ibatis you could use different dtd schemas. Check it please in the schemas rules in mapper namespace= I used [dtd schema](http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd) and update with foreach and select keywords worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found a hack to making this working.  We enclosed update query inside  tag and returned the number of rows that were touched.